# Do low reputation users get pings in chat?

Tags: support, chat

There has been a user in our chat room who doesn't have the reputation required to chat.  We've mentioned him with an @, and I was wondering if he actually gets those pings even though he doesn't have the reputation required to respond.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am a low-rep user (5 right now, but 1 at the time of the test), and I get pings in chat.

[image: Screenshot of inbox message]

Answer (score 1):

When typing a name after an at sign, their name will show up in the autocompletion list if and only if they are pingable in that room. Source: [balpha’s post on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239590/show-profile-picture-in-chat-autocomplete/240013#240013).

I don’t know whether being present in the room recently is enough to be pingable, or whether you have to chat. Either way, the autocompletion will tell you if the person can be pinged.

Also, if you reply to a post, the user is pinged. That shouldn’t depend on reputation at all: if comments on a post were converted to chat, you should be able to ping anyone whose comments were converted, even if they are not allowed to chat.

See also [this answer by balpha](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/938/what-are-the-rules-for-when-chat-messages-appear-in-a-users-inbox/939#939).

Comment: Although now that I think about it, I pinged someone from a newly created room once and the ping worked even though it wouldn’t autocomplete... Maybe there are more rules related to pinging across rooms that aren’t described in balpha’s answers above.